# Returning a value from a prompt dialog

Tags: c#

I have an application that reads through a bunch of text and looks for certain values, when these are picked up the user is prompted with a dialog box to enter a new value.

The issue I am having is that I cannot seem to call this value outside of its method.

Below is the code that calls the prompt:

```
return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
```

When the user adds the value this is returned as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text.get returned  "1234"  string
```

What I am now wanting to do is call this value in another method so that I can do string.Replace.

Any help is appreciated.

** **EDIT** **

Full method is as below;

```
public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
{
    Form prompt = new Form()
    {
        Width = 500,
        Height = 150,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
        Text = caption,
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    };
    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Add", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
    prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

    return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
```

Comment: Define `textBox` as `public` to have access after dialog is closed.

Comment: @i486 , sorry I don't think I follow, the method that this is in is a public static void but how t would you define a single element?

Comment: The dialog returns only `DialogResult` - `OK`, `Cancel`, etc. When the result is `OK` you can read controls in dialog the check their values from the calling method. You can also do this processing on click of OK button before the dialog is closed and cancel closing if values are wrong. Capture OnClick event for OK button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a property with a public getter on your prompt dialog.
You can read the value from that property after ShowDialog has been called.  In fact, as long as the form is not disposed, you can access that property.

```
using( var frm = new PromptForm())
{
   if( frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
   {
       var s = frm.SomeProperty;
   }
}
```